# Change color of gridviewitem based on values in it (store App 8.1)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I want to change the color of the gridviewitem depending on the values in a textblock contained in the gridviewitem.

```
 <GridViewItem x:Name="IdeaGridView" Loaded="IdeaGridView_Loaded"
                         DataContext="{Binding}" Height="150" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                        <StackPanel Height="150" >
                            <StackPanel Background="#CC00CC" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250" Height="100">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                   Style="{StaticResource TxtStyle1}" ></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                   Style="{StaticResource TxtStyle2}" ></TextBlock>

                            </StackPanel>
                            <Grid  Background="Purple" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="50">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                    <Image Height="20" Width="20"  Source="Assets/phone.png"></Image>
                                    <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource TxtStyle3}" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                                Text="{Binding Type}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </GridViewItem>
```

I want to set the color of gridviewitem based on the value of the property **"Category"**.. The gridview is having an object as the itemssource. So I want to change the color based on some properties. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this could work:

```
 class CategoryToColorConverter: IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
    if((bool)value)
        return Colors.White;
    else
        return Colors.Black;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
      if((bool)value)
          return Colors.Black;
             else
          return Colors.White;
    }
}
```

and Binding should work like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
        <Common:CategoryToColorConverter x:Key="CategoryToColorConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>

...Color={Binding Category,Converter={StaticResource CategoryToColorConverter}}...
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom [`IValueConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that can convert *Category* values into colors. Alternatively, you could move the color logic into the ViewModel and directly provide a *Color* property.